# Convert Angular 4 web app to Angular Universal app

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have a requirement to convert Angular 4 web app to [**Angular Universal**](https://universal.angular.io/).The reason for that is currently, the web app is not able to be properly indexed by Google (and Facebook social previews thumbnails) because it's a single page app and rendered on the client side.So now I need to implement Angular Universal, server-side rendering.

I got the knowledge of how to create a new Angular Universal app using [**this great video series**](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFaW_8zE4amO5dOfz8QyBJkoKONvIxrM2).

**Question:** Can you please tell me the direction which I have to follow the convert existing app as an Angular Universal one.Maybe a nice URL or steps or whatever the direction will be highly appreciated.

**Note:** Here angular version is not a problem.Either `2` or `4`.

Comment: What did you mean by `abandoned`? We can't use it further or what? @estus

Comment: It is written with big black letters https://github.com/angular/universal . A4 isn't supported by Universal. A4 has different API for server-side rendering.

Comment: OK.I have A4 web app.So can I make it as an Angular Universal app(4)? @estus

Comment: There are 4 links above. They explain everything.

Comment: Hmm..It seems those URLs are very important.So can you construct a small answer for this post? Hope it'll help everyone. @estus

Comment: I'm still figuring out how to deal with platform-server. Will probably revisit this question once I will be able to give a good answer. Btw, currently such broad questions are considered offtopic on SO and often closed.

Comment: This is not a broad question.Very straight forward one.How to convert the Angular app to Angular universal app? Must have only one path.But I don't know it yet. @estus

Comment: It does work, and I have made it work on several occasions, but it has yet to leave the lab ;)  I have been following this for like 6 months,  they haven't really solidified anything and it's been a bit of a goose chase,  and as of a couple weeks ago they were just waiting for some key pieces to be in v4 core - platform-server etc.  They are supposed to be coming out with docs, examples and a list of engines, but unless your using .net you don't have a lot to go by yet?

Comment: Hi, I too was looking for the same requirement and I stumbled upon this blog. Hope it helps.
https://medium.com/platformer-blog/enabling-server-side-rendering-on-an-existing-angular-application-with-angular-universal-5fdf7549b928.

Answer (score 5):

From [this blog](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal)) ([web archive backup](http://web.archive.org/web/20170825151440/https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal)))

First `npm install --save @angular/platform-server @angular/animations`

Edit `/src/app/app.module.ts` and change the BrowserModule import to `BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'your-app-name'}),`

Create a file `/src/app/app.server.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    ServerModule,
    AppModule
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppServerModule { }
```

Create a file `/src/server.ts`

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server'
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory'
import * as express from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

const PORT = 4000;

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

let template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const opts = { document: template, url: options.req.url };

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src')

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}!`);
});
```

Edit `/src/tsconfig.app.json` and add `server.ts` to the `exclude` array

Edit `/tsconfig.json` and after the `"compilerOptions"` node add the following

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./dist/ngfactory",
    "entryModule": "./src/app/app.module#AppModule"
}
```

Edit `package.json` and change the `"scripts"` section by adding `"prestart"` and altering `"start"`

```
"prestart": "ng build --prod && ngc",
"start": "ts-node src/server.ts"
```

You can now type `npm run start` in your console/terminal window and it will build everything and start serving on port 4000.

It doesn't watch the source or do hot-module-replacing etc, but once the server is running you can also type `ng serve` (assuming you are using the @angular/cli npm package) in another window and edit your single-page-app as you normally would and use `npm run start` only when rebuilding or changing server code.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Universal is a better choice with regards to better SEO indexing. You have raised very nice concern about the migration of current Angular 4 project to Universal. However, with ANgular 4 release they have packaged universal with it. I will write a tutorial regarding it and share it with you soon.

However, you can try `ng-universal-cli`?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-universal-cli

With this, you can setup your new Angular 4 Univeral project with one command `ngu new <project-name>`

You can then move your existing project files to this newly created project.

Comment: Did you write a tutorial?