# Converting an Angular 4 Web app to Angular Universal

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-universal

I currently have a web app that is running on Angular 4 and express-node.js in the backend. Due to problems with SEO, I want to migrate to Universal. But I would like to do so with minimal changes in my codebase, especially how my `server.js` is currently handled. In all guides I have seen and even in this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462246/convert-angular-4-web-app-to-angular-universal-app), the server is written in Typescript from scratch. Since I already have a Javascript server present, I want to reuse it.

Currently my project is structured overall as

```
├───dist
│   ├───assets
|   └───main.bundle.js
├───node_modules
├───server
|   ├───routes
|   ├───models
|   └───modules
├───src
|   ├───app
|   ├───assets
|   └───main.ts
└───server.js
```

Is there a way to add the server side angular code to the current structure itself?

**EDIT:** Adding highly stripped *server.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bugsnag.requestHandler);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

let host = '';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    host = 'localhost:3001';
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    host = 'example.com';
}

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Server 404 request: ${req.originalUrl}`);
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'))
});

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.send({
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
        console.log(err);
    });
}

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    app.use(bugsnag.errorHandler);
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.send({
            message: err.message,
            error: {}
        });
    });
}

module.exports = app;
```

The original code can be found in this [commit](https://github.com/SayakMukhopadhyay/elitebgs/blob/b465924e01e7b39039a7be371c9f475aa568a880/server.js)

Comment: What problems are you running into with SEO?

Comment: @MikeK. Since Angular generates the webpage on the client side, the browser and crawlers have no idea what the webpage consists of including any links withing it. To overcome this, Server Side Rendering is the recommended way using Angular Universal.

Comment: Can you show your server.js?

Comment: Added the file requested.